# To display selected list-item values in another component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have 2 components called `list`(i,e Person list) and `details`(i,e Person details) which i am displaying like this:

[image]

**Here my requirements is:** On selecting particular `list-item` for ex:Person 1, I want to display the `Person 1` details on `details` component which present on the right side, something like this:

[image]

How can i  assign values for individual `list-item` (i,e Person 1, Person 2 ....) in `list` component and pass them to `details` component to display as shown in 2nd image.I saw some examples but they are not matching to my requirement.

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-kczke2?file=app/details/details.component.html)

Comment: first of all you should have ages data paired in some way to the persons data. you could create a typescript model for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several way to communicate among different components. In your case you can use Services to communicate.

Working demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-nh4hik

#### person.service.ts

This is the service which will communicate between one component to another.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject , Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {

  person$ = new Subject();

  public setPerson(person){
    this.person$.next(person);
  }

  public getPerson() : Observable<any>{
    return this.person$.asObservable();
  }

}
```

#### List Component

```
export class ListComponent {

  constructor(private personService : PersonService){}

  public setSelected(person){
    this.personService.setPerson(person);
  }

}
```

#### DetailsComponent

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  person : any;
  constructor(private personService : PersonService){}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.personService.getPerson().subscribe(person=>{ //<-- subscribe 

      this.person = person;
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: In your `stackblitz` example you are displaying only name i, e (Person1, Person 2....) . I want the age also..:)

Comment: If possible please do it for 2-3 persons..:)

Comment: Updated the demo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..:)

Comment: Ok, let me check

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` to achieve that.

Declare a service like that:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService{
  private data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public dataEvent = this.data$.asObservable();

  public setData(data: any){
    this.data$.next(data);
  }
}
```

Inject the service into the `listComponent`

```
constructor(
  ...
  private serivice: YourService
) {
...
}
```

add a function that trigger the BehaviorSubject:

```
function sendData(data){
  this.service.setData(data);
}
```

**Note**: in this example I assume that when you click on a element, it will fire this function. Let's assume your html being something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of yourList>
  <span (click)="sendData(item)>{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

In the `detailsComponent` catch the result from the BehaviorSubject (inject the service first):

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.service.dataEvent
  .subscribe(res => {
    if(!!res){
      this.dataDetail = res;
    }
  });
}
```

then in the .html, you could've something like that:

```
<span>Name: {{dataDetail.name}}</span>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d64vtt

Answer (score 0):

Different approach based on components input/output:

Add onSelectionChange to material list:

```
(onSelectionChange)="personSelected(event)"
```

Add output to your list component:

```
@Output() onPersonSelect = new EventEmitter<any>();;
```

In personSelected call onPersonSelect emit:

```
personSelected(event) {
    this.onPersonSelect.emit(event);
}
```

In app component add listener to list component:

```
personSelectedListener(event) {
    this.selectedPerson = event;
}
```

And add it to list:

```
<app-list (onPersonSelect)="personSelectedListener"></app-list>
```

Finally pass selected person to detains component:

```
<app-details [selectedPerson]="selectedPerson"></app-details>
```

Accept input parameter in details component and do what ever you want:

```
@Input() selectedPerson;
```

In template

```
<h4> Person Details </h4>
<div>Selected person is {{selectedPerson}}</div>
```