# Communication between re usable components using services

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-services

I have created two `generic components` called **1)list** and **2)details** so that i can re use them:

The components looks like this:

[image]

Now i am re using the these component in another components called **SCHOOL** and **COLLEGE** which will displayed like this:

[image]

Now

- If i click on the `list-item`(for ex school 1) from the `list` component present in **SCHOOL** component. I want to display that particular clicked item details(Ex: Name,email) on right side (i,e on details page/component).
- If i click on the `list-item`(for ex college 1) from the `list` component present in **COLLEGE** component. I want to display that particular clicked item details(Ex: Name,email) on right side (i,e on details page/component).

I got solution by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188163/to-display-selected-list-item-values-in-another-component/53188409?noredirect=1#comment93266125_53188409) . In this example communication is happening between the components using `services`. **But in my condition i am re using the component**. How can i use the `services` when i am re using the component.

Stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-lptyvt?file=app%2Fcollege%2Fcollege.component.html)

Comment: You need to use evenEmitter to figure it out which item is being clicked and thn accordingly display information. PS: Use `@output`

Comment: Can you include the service in the Stackblitz demo?

Comment: okay, i will update the DEMO.

Comment: I have created **services** inside **COLLEGE** component. Here is the updated stackblitz link :  `https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-ny9ddc?file=app/details/details.component.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current scenario, the best would be to leverage `@Input` and `@Output` decorators.

> You need to have @Input for details component which can get the contact details from its component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent {

  @Input()
  public contact;

}
```

> List component will emit the value on selection of any items from the list.

```
export class ListComponent {

  @Output()
  public select;

  public onSelect(contact){
     this.select.emit(contact);
  }

}
```

> School and College component can get the the emitted value from the List Component and pass it to details component .

```
<div class="header">
   <h3>SCHOOL</h3>
  <div  class="left">
      <app-list  [contacts]="contacts" ></app-list>
  </div>
    <div  class="right">
      <app-details></app-details>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working copy - https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-ilxisk

Comment: Thanks a lot....:)

Comment: I also recommend this solution

Comment: Answer is already provided for this. What else you are looking for ?

Comment: Please see the comment below the answer.